# Making a custom build in dojo 1.7.2

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I need some help please with my Dojo 1.7.2 custom build - the build works fine but returns an error in the browser.

Here's my profile file:

```javascript
dependencies = {
    layers: [
            {
                    // This is a specially named layer, literally 'dojo.js'
                    // adding dependencies to this layer will include the modules
                    // in addition to the standard dojo.js base APIs.
                    name: "dojo.js",
                    dependencies: [
                            "dijit.registry",
                            "dijit.Dialog",
                            "dijit.Tooltip",
                            "dijit.form.Button",
                            "dijit.layout.ContentPane"
                    ]
            }
    ],

    prefixes: [
            [ "dijit", "../dijit" ],
            [ "dojox", "../dojox" ]
    ]
```

}

I don't think I need to add "digit.registry" - the generated dojo.js file doesn't change with or without it.  I made it a dependency since I use digit.byId

here's how I build:

```sh
./build.sh -r --profile profiles/my.profile.js --releaseDir /my/release/directory
```

I then include the generated dojo.js in my html code.  When the page loads, the javascript console reveals the error "_5c4 is not a function" when attempting to do something with digit.byId.

When I instead load the full Dojo from ajax.googleapis.com, everything works perfectly.

Should I be including ../dijit/dijit.js in the html as well?

Comment: dijit/dijit is sometimes built as a separate layer, but that's not necessary.  The way you have it configured, all the intermediate dijit dependencies (dijit/_base/*, dijit/_Widget, etc.) should all be built into a single layer called dojo.js.  You should not need to explicitly include dijit/dijit as a dependency, as it is already implied by the modules you've included.

Answer (score 0):

check your spelling digit->dijit

Comment: Thanks, that was just a mistype.  Profile file did not have "digit"

Comment: you should correct your question, above.  Also, if you could provide a bit more context about the error -- can you identify the surrounding lines where _5c4 occurs?  Is it your code or dojo's?

Comment: The _5c4 error is in dojo.js.  I also notice that the browser attempts to include selector/acme.js, which I didn’t move to the web server.  I thought I only needed to move dojo.js?

Comment: You'd best move the entire tree to the webserver, at least you have the build working and know what's going on.  In order to bake the selector/acme into your layer file, you need to use the selectorEngine option.  You can find (a tutorial)[http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/build/] on the Dojo site.  Related documentation links are found at the bottom of that tutorial